# jQuery Mobile as Web CRM

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, crm

I got a new project where I need to develop a Web Based CRM Sofware. I will be using PHP and MYSQL as my backend, for my frontend I need a UI framework. I found jQuery Mobile really good, its fully ajax, its really simple in coding and somewhat it gives a software feeling. I also saw Sencha Ext js and Adobe flex, I dont want to use Sencha cause I dont have that much time to learn it and flex is flash so cant use it.

My question is can I use jQuery mobile as my frontend, I know it is meant for mobile development. But can I use it in web based DESKTOP softwares. Are their any drawbacks of using jQuery Mobile?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can easily use is as a desktop website frontend but there are few problems.

1. jQuery Mobile widgets are built with mobile devices in mind so all of its components and widgets have that mobile app's look. For me this is not a big problem, mainly because all of those components can be easily visually modified.
2. Unlike mobile devices on desktop browsers you will have a full speed advantage. Transitions will work just fine, anti-aliasing will work correctly (rounded borders on Android <2.3 are terrible), everything will work without any problems. You should only concern your self  with older versions of IE (but this is a constant problem).
3. One other big problem is a layout. You need to understand jQM was built with mobile phones on mind, so you will need to create a basic layout inside your content before you start adding components and widgets. In any other case a select menu will stretch from one side of screen to an other side (Not pretty at all).

Everything I mentioned is not a big problem, and if you already have a knowledge of jQuery they by all means use jQuery Mobile as a frontend.

Comment: Thanks, this is really going to help me. I ll go ahead with jQuery Mobile